# No abre el navegador ejecucíón de Script con Jenkins Selenium Maven

Tags: batch, navegador-web, jenkins, ejecutar

Se ejecuta un Script de automatización desde selenium con Jenkins , pero no abre el navegador , si lo hace desde Eclipse y por linea de comandos

Comment: Hola, buenas tardes, podrás poner el código de tu script para que de esa forma podamos ayudarte de una mejor forma?

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de que el esclavo de jenkins puede abrir aplicaciones de escritorio, si es un servidor Linux que tenga las X instaladas, si es un Windows, que el usuario que está ejecutando el slave.jar tiene escritorio (si es un servicio de windows).
Haz la prueba simple de abrir el navegador :

```
   sh 'firefox'
```

o si es windows :

```
  bat 'firefox'
```